# What is the difference between web3 filter methods and subscribe methods?

Tags: web3.py, evm, events

What is the difference between the web3 filter methods and the subscribe ones?:

Filter methods:

[image]

Subscribe methods:

[image]

I cannot see to understand the difference. And which one you would recommend in each situation.

In my personal case, i need to read ERC1155 'TransferSingle' and 'TransferBatch' events from a particular shared contract in opensea.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In particular, `eth_subscribe` will only get *new* events.  There is no built-in way to say "Starting with historical block N, get me all logs matching the filter criteria (e.g. `TransferSingle` events) for a contract address X and then wait and keep watching for new logs to appear."   You have to craft this logic yourself, including protecting against race conditions.

Also:  note that web3.js supports

```
web3.eth.subscribe(type [, options] [, callback]);
```

but web3.py does not support the `subscribe` method (v6.1.0, as of 4-Jun-2023)